# Insert JSON into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, json

I'm new to python and trying to work out how to insert some json into mysql. I'm running a shell script i already have which outputs the json.

```
balance = subprocess.check_output([shell_script, 'all'])

conn = MySQLdb.connect(all my info)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#ive tried a few different things but this is the last one i tried
for i in balance.items():
term = i[0]
urls = json.dumps(i[1])
sql = """INSERT INTO balance (name, balance) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
cursor.execute(sql, (term, urls))
```

But everything i try i get

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Here is what the output looks like of the shell script

```
{
"" : 52,
"bob" : 12,
"john" : 2,
"peter" : 4
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `subprocess.check_output()` is *always* a string, but you seem to expect it to be a dictionary:

```
balance = subprocess.check_output([shell_script, 'all'])

# ...

for i in balance.items():
```

*Load* the object from the JSON output of the command first:

```
balance = subprocess.check_output([shell_script, 'all'])
balance = json.loads(balance)

conn = MySQLdb.connect(all my info)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO balance (name, balance) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

for term, urls in balance.items():
    cursor.execute(sql, (term, urls))
```

There is no need to dump the `urls` integer to JSON again.

Comment: Good answer thanks. Working, will accept it in 9mins when it allows me.